# Xuggler NoClassDefFoundError using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, media, xuggler

I have written the following code below:

```
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer;

public class MediaPlayer {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        IContainer container = IContainer.make();

        if(container.open("file:///homes/sa303/NetBeansProjects/MoviePlayer1/src/Trailer/IronMan3.mp4", 
                           IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not open");
        }
    }
}
```

I based it on the video tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdW6tUql154

However, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

I have saved the `xuggle-xuggler.jar` file in the class path and it hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: get slf4j.jar and add to classpath: http://www.slf4j.org/download.html

Comment: Thanks. I think I sort of understood the errors and added the following extra jar files in the class path:
logback-classic-0.9.jar, logback-core-0.9.6.jar. However, now I have a different error:
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.<init>(Lch/qos/logback/classic/LoggerContext;)V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause Could be un-availability of dependency jars or version conflicts.

The following jars combination worked fine for me:

xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
logback-core-1.0.0.jar
logback-classic-1.0.0.jar

Note: Add them in the library folder using "Add jar/Folder" Option.